# group by name order

Tags: c#, linq

There are two types "files" and "folders" I want to group by files and folders but folders must be on top. how can I do this in LINQ?

```
public class DocumentItem
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<DocumentItem> result = SPHelper.GetList().OrderBy(x => x.Type).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a little confusing. Can you please provide some sample data and the expected output that you require?

Comment: first group by Type and then sort by Type descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855.aspx) method to get the reverse sort by `Type`:

```
var result = SPHelper.GetList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Type).ToList();
```

Can't say why do you need grouping by type in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Either add a property to DocumentItem to represent that higher priority or treat them as separate groups and in the end add both, in order, to a final collection.

Answer (score 0):

**OrderByDescending** will do the trick in this specific case, as follows:

```
List<DocumentItem> result = SPHelper.GetList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Type).ToList();
```

If you need also need to sort within each group, say alphabetically, then you can append this query with **ThenBy**:

```
List<DocumentItem> result = SPHelper.GetList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Type)
                            .ThenBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

One last option can be sorting by boolean condition, as follows:

```
List<DocumentItem> result = SPHelper.GetList()
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Type == "Folder").ToList();
```

Here, **OrderByDescending** sorts from True to False, thus groups your entities.